# Can't read data from a text file

Tags: java, file

I have text file with name `pwd.txt` located in `projectfolder->src->pwd.txt`
and I am accessing this file as follows:

```
File f1 = new File("src\\pwd.txt");
if(f1.exists()==false){
    System.out.println("file not");
}
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
while ((ch = fr.read()) != -1) {
    pass = pass + (char) ch;
}
LoginForm.pwd = pass;
fr.close();
```

Well, let me tell you first that I am able to access this file when running within the `IDE` (Eclipse) but I am not able to access that file`pwd.txt` when I have made the `jar` file. 
When i saw the contents of that `jar` file, I can see the file pwd.txt

Comment: Are you trying to read this file from within the .jar, or external to the .jar? Look up this duplicate answer of [Reading a resource file from within jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar). If external to the .jar, provide an absolute path.

Comment: You cannot access or open files compressed in a .zip file using `File` or `FileReader`

Comment: in a jar file, you need to load this file via the classloader. getClass().getClassloader().getResource("pwd.txt")

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, i hope it will help you.

```
BufferedReader br = null;

//first open the file
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("src\\pwd.txt")));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found!");
    return;
}

try {
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR:"+e);
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code so that the braces align nicely. Please do that yourself the next time. You can choose any style of braces and spaces that you want, just make it consistent.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am new here so i appreciate your advice i will keep that in mind.